# How i can do a *ngFor in a array of objects that i don't know the name property?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have this array called `dadosRelatorio` that i need to iterate in my template, this array i get in a http request:

```
[{"id": 1,
  "name": "a",
  "class":[{
     "Inglês":[{
        "id": 1,
        "code": "teste"
     },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "teste 2"
     }],
     "Espanhol":[{
        "id": 1,
        "code": "a"
     }]
   }]
}]
```

How i can iterate the objects inside class if they have different names property? Sometimes the name can be "Inglês" and sometimes can be "Espanhol" and other names...

When i know the name of the property i do this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let aluno of dadosRelatorio" class="div-aluno">
       <span>Aluno: {{ aluno.name }}</span>
       <div *ngFor="let classe of aluno.class">
          <div *ngFor="let idioma of classe. ???>

          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

But how i can iterate the object inside class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may iterate using the `keyvalue` pipe as shown below:

```
<div *ngFor="let aluno of dadosRelatorio" class="div-aluno">
    <span>Aluno: {{ aluno.name }}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let classe of aluno.class | keyvalue">
        <div> {{classe.key}}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let type of classe.value | keyvalue">
            {{type.key}}
            <div *ngFor="let data of type.value | keyvalue">
                {{data.value.id }}
                {{data.value.code }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This way i'm getting: Inglês (classe.key)
0 (type.key)
but te type.value in id and code is empty

Comment: Seems to work [fine here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-del-qtrmuu). Could you please check?

Comment: i think my real array have a little difference, but i think that i get the properly result with:<div *ngFor="let classe of aluno.class | keyvalue" class="row mx-1 mt-4">

        {{classe.key}}

        <div *ngFor="let type of classe.value | keyvalue" class="row mt-2 mx-1">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h6>{{ type.key }}</h6>
            <h6>{{ type.value.code }}</h6>
          </div>

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate an object keys using `Object.keys`.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys.

edit: You can also use the keyvalue pipe as describe in the official documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

I thought there was a ngForIn directive as well, but I cant find the doc.

Comment: I try with the pipe keyvalue: <div *ngFor="let item of classe | keyvalue"> but i'm getting: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: its working fine here with angular 8 and your example object